# Installing Ubuntu 18.04.2 Server stalls at configuring network connections

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, configure

Installing Ubuntu 18.04.2 Server on a Dell T310 PowerEdge server.  It has two built in network connections.  The installer says there isn't a response from the DHCP server (my home router) on either interface.  I tried configuring eth0 manually:
Netmask - 192.168.1.0/24
Static IP - 192.168.1.252
DNS - 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
Search domain - google.com

Trying to save these settings causes the installer to go back a few steps to "Select language"

Help?

**EDIT**
After trying everything I could think of - connecting both NICs to the network (installer again reports no response from DHCP server), configuring eth1 first, bonding the two NICs together and then configuring them, disabling the two NICs in the UEFI (on this box someone can't disable only one - it's all or nothing) (I might have tried one or two other things but can't remember them now), I gave up. It appears to be a bug in the Subiquity installer and I'll file a bug report.

My workaround was to use the ["traditional" installer](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) and the box is up, running, and updated.

Answer (score 0):

A bug report was filed on Netplan:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1831373